# How to change column names for mrset in R?

Tags: r, datatable, spss, expss

I am trying to create crosstabs I have a dataframe in which I have multiple select questions. I am importing the data frame from SPSS file using foreign and expss package. I am creating the multiple select questions using the mrset function. Here's the demo code for this to make it clear.

```
Banner1 = w %>% 
  tab_cells(mrset(as.category( temp1,counted_value = "Checked"))) %>%
  tab_cols(total(),mrset(as.category( temp2, counted_value = "Checked"))) %>% 
  tab_stat_cases(total_row_position = "none",label = "")
  tab_pivot(Banner1)
```

The datatable imported looks like this

```
               Total    Q12_1      Q12_2     Q12_3     Q12_4     Q12_5     
                 A        B          C         D          E        F        

Total Cases     803   34        18         14        38       37    

Q13_1           64        11         7      8     9    7                


Q13_2            12         54       54         43       13       12 


Q13_3           67           54      23          21          6      4
```

Sorry about the alignment here....So this is the imported dataset.

Coming to the problem, As you can see this dataset has column labels as Question numbers and not variable labels. For single select questions everything works fine. Is there any function I can change the colnames for mrset functions dynamically?
 The desired output should be something like this. For eg,

```
               Total    Apple     Mango    Banana    Orange     Grapes     
                 A        B          C         D          E        F        

Total Cases     803   34        18         14        38       37    

Apple           64        11         7      8     9    7                


Mango           12         54       54         43       13       12 


banana         67           54      23          21          6      4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this variables (q12_1, q12_2 and etc) have labels in the original files? If not you can use `apply_labels` function. For help type `?apply_labels` in the console.

Comment: @GregoryDemin yes, the variable labels are defined in the original files. I got the output using var_lab function. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't help without reproducible example or, at least, sample of your data.